# User enter invalid email format label transition error

Tags: css

When user enter invalid email format then the style of label with placeholder and invalid email address get combine.

- Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pac87eu/)

code is

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="group">      
    <input type="text" name ="user" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">      
    <input type="email"required >
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code, Hope it work's

```css
body{
  padding-top:20px;
}
.fieldOuter {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 16px
}
.fieldOuter input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 1s;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #666
}
.fieldOuter label {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top: 0;
  line-height:15px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fieldOuter input:focus + label {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -18px;  
}
.fieldOuter input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldOuter">
<input id="Name" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"  onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name'" type="text" />
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="fieldOuter">
<input id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"  onblur="this.placeholder = 'Last Name'"type="text" />
  <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input:invalid ~ label {
         top:-20px;
         font-size:14px;
         color:red;
       }
```

Add this to the CSS code. The email label will remain **red** until it does not contain a proper format